# Proportional Editing Causing Blender to Hang

Tags: proportional-editing

I'm not entirely sure how I can be helped, but I wondered if anyone has experienced Blender hanging while using proportional editing.

I am editing a model for a halloween short, and using proportional editing to move some accessories (fairly high poly count - nothing silly). I managed to do it initially, though not with some hangs, but now I cannot move anything and Blender hangs for at least 2 minutes at a time.

The component of the model is weighted to an armature, and I am doing the edit in rest mode. What changes I have made have worked with the armature, but I am trying to fine tune it.

I propose now to import the model and armature into a fresh Blender file.

I generally use Linux and 2.90.1 and I tried the same thing with same results in 2.83 on the Mac. I am not optimistic that it will resolve the problem.[image: Model component causing Blender to hang in proportional editing mode]

Comment: As suspected, importing into a new project did not really work, but by focussing on the 2 objects, the accessories and the pumpkin I could eventually make the adjustments though not without long, long hangs.